# Minimizing a series of SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a series of SQL queries to output number values for all 12 months.

```
$chartIncomejan        = $query->fetch("SELECT *, SUM(rent_amount) AS 'num' FROM transaction WHERE paid_on LIKE '%2015-01%'");
$chartIncomefeb        = $query->fetch("SELECT *, SUM(rent_amount) AS 'num' FROM transaction WHERE paid_on LIKE '%2015-02%'");
$chartIncomemar        = $query->fetch("SELECT *, SUM(rent_amount) AS 'num' FROM transaction WHERE paid_on LIKE '%2015-03%'");
$chartIncomeapr        = $query->fetch("SELECT *, SUM(rent_amount) AS 'num' FROM transaction WHERE paid_on LIKE '%2015-04%'");
...
```

This is my code for the output

```
if ($chartIncomejan['num'] > '0') { echo $chartIncomejan['num'].','; } else { echo '0,'; }
if ($chartIncomefeb['num'] > '0') { echo $chartIncomefeb['num'].','; } else { echo '0,'; }
if ($chartIncomemar['num'] > '0') { echo $chartIncomemar['num'].','; } else { echo '0,'; }
if ($chartIncomeapr['num'] > '0') { echo $chartIncomeapr['num'].','; } else { echo '0,'; }
...
```

And it echos as a list of comma separated values `1,2,3,4,5,6,`...etc

I would like to minimize this code into the smallest amount of code possible, but I'm not sure where to start. Should I do arrays? Maybe a foreach statement? If you can show an example (not necessarily with my code) that would be very helpful also.

Comment: I don't know why I'm being downvoted. It's a legitimate question from somebody who's genuinely trying to learn best practices...

Comment: What data type is the `paid_on` column

Comment: `paid_on` is TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use something like this ( untested )

```
/* Assuming mysqli */

$sql="select *, sum(`rent_amount`) as 'num' from `transaction`
    where year(`paid_on`)=year( now() )
    group by month(`paid_on`);";

$res=$conn->query( $sql );

if( $res ){
    $chartIncomes=$res->fetch_all();

    /* process array to your needs */
    echo '<pre>',print_r($chartIncomes,true),'</pre>'
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: This helped me the most to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the condition and collect all the data in one query?

```
$chartIncome = $query->fetch("SELECT *, SUM(rent_amount) AS 'num' FROM transaction WHERE paid_on BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-04-31'");
```

That is assuming that your column `paid_on` is **DATE**. You will get all data in `$chartIncome` and then you'd just do something like:

```
echo $chartIncome['num'].',';
```

The condition is not necessary if you just always show the result

Comment: `paid_on` is actually a TIMESTAMP. Is it still plausible if I were to do something like `BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-04-31 23:59:59'`? I tried it but it outputs one large sum where I'm looking for the sum of each month in a list.